# Use html inside Latex

Tags: html, css

I'm having a html and css code of a figure, and wanna insert this code inside the latex file such that when i compile the document it show me the figure.

Comment: use an html system such as a web browser to print the figure to pdf, then use `\includegraphics` to include in to latex

Comment: What you always can do is entering ctan html and other terms to your search engine. Also search this site, including search via tags.